# wp_dropdown_categories() show elements checkbox

Tags: categories, walker

I have a code in my `functions.php` and I would like to use `wp_dropdown_categories` for displaying list product categories but I wont in "select" only "checkbox".

I edited my code in `functions.php` and it looks like this now:

```php
class List_Categories_Radiobuttons extends Walker_Category {
    function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0) {
        $category_name = esc_attr( $category->name );
        $radiobutton = '<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="' . $category_name . '" id="flexCheckDefault' . $category_name . '"><label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault' . $category_name . '">' . $category_name . '</label>';
        $output .= '<span class="form-check">'.$radiobutton.'</span>';
    }
    function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0) {
        $output .= '';
    }
}
```

and I add code in my template

```
<?php 
                        $args = array(
                            'taxonomy' => 'pa_rozmiar',
                            'name' => 'pa_rozmiar',
                            'value_field' => 'slug',
                            'class' => 'd-none form-check',
                            'walker' => new List_Categories_Radiobuttons
                        );
                        wp_dropdown_categories( $args );

                        ?>
```

I have a problem because the first position is outside my markers `span`. Where I am making a mistake?

Comment: Would it not be easier to fetch the categories as an array then do a `foreach`? `wp_dropdown_categories` is just one way of listing terms in a taxonomy, there are others, e.g. `get_terms` or `wp_get_post_terms` etc

Answer (score 0):

Good for [@Tom J Nowell♦](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/users/736/tom-j-nowell) solution would be more properly. But it still could fulfill the goal which add the extra function in your class.

```php
class List_Categories_Radiobuttons extends Walker_Category
{
  function start_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0)
  {
    $category_name = esc_attr($category->name);
    $radiobutton = '<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="' . $category_name . '" id="flexCheckDefault' . $category_name . '"><label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault' . $category_name . '">' . $category_name . '</label>';
    $output .= '<span class="form-check">' . $this->content_el() . '</span>';
  }

  function end_el(&$output, $category, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $current_object_id = 0)
  {
    $output .= '';
  }

  private function content_el()
  {
    $args = array(
      'taxonomy' => 'pa_rozmiar',
      'name' => 'pa_rozmiar',
      'value_field' => 'slug',
      'class' => 'd-none form-check',
      'walker' => new List_Categories_Radiobuttons
    );
    wp_dropdown_categories($args);
  }
}
```

The arguments is fixed so far.You could setup the argument and call the function when turn public. Then generate your `$output` later when you call `end_el`.There is more flexible is use `DOMDocument` to add your document node, and it would be manipulate like JavaScript(or JQuery) and easily.

Answer (score 0):

Thank You my friends, I used get_terms and showed the list with foreach. Below is a code snippet

```
$rozmiar = get_terms('pa_rozmiar');
                            
                            foreach ($rozmiar as $roz){
                                echo '<div class="form-check">';
                                echo '<input class="form-check-input" type="checkbox" value="'.$roz->name.'" id="flexCheckDefault'.$roz->term_id.'">';
                                echo '<label class="form-check-label" for="flexCheckDefault'.$roz->term_id.'">'.$roz->name.'</label>';
                                echo '</div>';
                            }
```